# Javascript onclick do not execute until click

Tags: javascript

I am working in Microsoft Framework to create an application customizer which can only contain html code as a string. I created the html I want to render and need to add some functionality to open a link via a javascript method givien by Microsoft Teams. The main problem though is that it fires directly. I usually add an addListener to the method, but since it has to be HTML in a .ts file I cannot do that. So I am wondering except for that method what else would prevent the browser from triggering my openLink function from executing immediately.

I also cannot use React code where it would be as simple as onClick={() => sth(1)}.

My Code:

```
private _renderTopBar(navData, context) {

    const { logoUrl, navigation } = navData;
    let logo = logoUrl.replace('-my', '');


    function openLink(url) {
        console.log('got executed...')
    }


    return `
        <section class="${styles.top}">
        <div class="${styles.headerRow}">
            <div class="${styles.mainHeader}">
            <div class="${styles.logoCell}"><img src="${'https://one365demo.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/Style%20Library/hublogo.png'}" /></div>
            <div class="${styles.titleCell}">
                <a href="` + openLink('http://www.telegraaf.nl') + `" id="start">Start</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
    `;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Try: `<a onclick="` + openLink('http://www.telegraaf.nl') + `" href="#someurl" id="start">Start</button>` erh, the SO text editor is interpreting my " ` " as the "code" bracket markup, but you get the idea.

Comment: unfortunately no avail, it isn't related to the href though. when the code loads within the browser, it directly fires the event.

Comment: Martin is right, you do need to drop the excess backticks. What's also missing is that any JS function call inside `href` has to be preceded by `javascript:`. So write this: `<a href="javascript:openLink('http://www.telegraaf.nl')" id="start">Start</a>`. Though not sure if this will work anyway, since `openLink` has to be in the global scope, and I don't think it is. Is this .NET or some other framework?